# how do you pull mysql results from field equaling multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

so I have a table with a row that contains categories along with other rows.

so there is:

```
id (post id)
category (news, videos, music, photos, tutorials, coming-soon, etc..)
title (title of post)
desc (short meta desc of post)
post (the actual post)
etc...
```

So what i'm trying to do, for example, is pull all posts in the `music, videos and photos` categories, and ignore everything else.

The way I have it now is I am selecting `WHERE category != 'news' AND category != 'tutorials' AND category != 'coming_soon'.... etc, etc.,` but there are about 12 category in total, meaning I'm doing that 9 times!

Is there is better way to write that WHERE statement so that wouldn't have to reference all the other ones, and just reference the ones I want instead?

I tried `WHERE category = 'videos' AND category = 'music' AND category = 'photos'` but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic you want is:

```
WHERE category = 'videos' OR category = 'music' OR category = 'photos'
```

Better yet, just use `IN`:

```
WHERE category IN ('videos', 'music', 'photos')
```